# JSON Array Not Showing All Values

Tags: android, json, arrays

I'm using JSONParser.java to show JSON data from a url

the url and the data are correct, they show some values of JSON (more than one)

but why this show only one value?

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> artikelList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(ArtikelURL);

        try {
            artikels = json.getJSONArray(TAG_ARTIKEL);

            for(int i = 0; i < artikels.length(); i++){
                JSONObject c = artikels.getJSONObject(i);

                // Storing each json item in variable
                String tanggal = c.getString(TAG_TGL);
                String judul = c.getString(TAG_JUDUL);
                String kutipan = c.getString(TAG_KUTIPAN);

                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();            
                map.put(TAG_TGL, tanggal);
                map.put(TAG_JUDUL, judul);
                map.put(TAG_KUTIPAN, kutipan);
                artikelList.add(map);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

This is my JSON data:

```
{
   "status":"1",
   "total":20,
   "artikel":[
      {
         "tanggal":"2013-08-07",
         "judul":"Article One",
         "kutipan":"Example of article quote..."
      },
      {
         "tanggal":"2013-07-23",
         "judul":"Article Two",
         "kutipan":"Example of article quote......"
      },
      {
         "tanggal":"2013-07-22",
         "judul":"Article Three",
         "kutipan":"Example of article quote......"
      },
      {
         "tanggal":"2013-03-16",
         "judul":"Article Four"",
         "kutipan":"Example of article quote,..."
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: what does your json response look like?

Comment: Could you post the sample url data and json response. So that every one can answer quick.

Comment: I have added JSON data above

Comment: @user2790880 there is an extra quotes **"** in json response check this line `"judul":"Article Four"",`  .... it should be `"judul":"Article Four",`

Comment: @CRUSADER: still not working

Comment: @user2790880 are you sure you are not getting `JSONException`... check log traces since you have added `e.printStackTrace();` statement

Comment: Ups, I got this: `FATAL EXCEPTION: main
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` what's wrong?

Comment: @user2790880 This exception is thrown when an application attempts to perform a networking operation on its main thread. [Run your code in AsyncTask](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6343299/2345913)

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON is invalid, there's an error in your line 22 at 3rd object of your array

> "judul":"Article Four"",

Correct JSON is

```
{
"status": "1",
"total": 20,
"artikel": [
    {
        "tanggal": "2013-08-07",
        "judul": "Article One",
        "kutipan": "Example of article quote..."
    },
    {
        "tanggal": "2013-07-23",
        "judul": "Article Two",
        "kutipan": "Example of article quote......"
    },
    {
        "tanggal": "2013-07-22",
        "judul": "Article Three",
        "kutipan": "Example of article quote......"
    },
    {
        "tanggal": "2013-03-16",
        "judul": "Article Four",
        "kutipan": "Exampleofarticlequote,..."
    }
]
}
```

Ok, Now you are getting Network related exception so, solution to this is, you've to use demo code like

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    new NetworkThread().execute();
}

class NetworkThread extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> artikelList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(ArtikelURL);

        try {
            JSONArray artikels = json.getJSONArray("artikel");

            for(int i = 0; i < artikels.length(); i++){
                JSONObject c = artikels.getJSONObject(i);

                // Storing each json item in variable
                String tanggal = c.getString(TAG_TGL);
                String judul = c.getString(TAG_JUDUL);
                String kutipan = c.getString(TAG_KUTIPAN);

                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put(TAG_TGL, tanggal);
                map.put(TAG_JUDUL, judul);
                map.put(TAG_KUTIPAN, kutipan);
                artikelList.add(map);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

    }
}
```

Don't forget to add this to AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: Have you replaced your JSON?

Comment: Yes, I do, I've changed it to `"judul": "Article Four",`

Comment: what kind of output are you having?

Comment: @user2790880 try this.

Comment: now I got this error: `FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.`

Comment: @user2790880 can you show that code for parsing json using asyncTask, because i think you've done UI related operation in doInBackGround method.

Comment: I already do that in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20289330/android-jsonarray-showing-only-one-value but still not showing all result :(

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON Is Invalid But assuming you have an outer Json Array for the JsonObject This implementation would work for your nested Json

```
      ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> artikelList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(ArtikelURL);

    try {
       JSONArray  a = json.getJSONArray(TAG_JSON);

        for(int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++){
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();   
         JSONObject c = a.getJSONObject(i);

            map.put(TAG_TOTAL, c.getString(TAG_TOTAL));
            map.put(TAG_STATUS, c.getString(TAG_STATUS));
            artikelList.add(map);
            JSONArray  akel = e.getJSONArray(artikel);
            if(akel != null){
          for(int j=0;j<akel.length();j++){
          HashMap<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
          JSONObject f = akel.getJSONObject(j);
          map2.put(TAG_TGL, f.getString(TAG_TGL));
          map2.put(TAG_JUDUL, f.getString(TAG_JUDUL));
          map2.put(TAG_KUTIPAN, f.getString(TAG_KUTIPAN));
          }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```